# ngSubmit and ngDisabled not working, but ngModel is bound to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This doesn't look any different than what I thought I would normally write when I put a form together in AngularJS, but for whatever reason ngSubmit is not working, and ngDisabled isn't disabling the button when the fields are empty.  I took the section and pasted it into a new project to see if it was just acting out due to some other dependencies, but it still doesn't work even after trimming the fat.  Can anyone see what is wrong, it's obvious after this amount of time I'm not going to see it myself.

I preloaded the form fields using the controller to verify that they are talking, interpolated the user data in pre tags which are bound to ng-model since I can see it update as I type, and there are no ng errors occuring, even looking at Chromes angular plugin it looks fine. But, login() is never invoked on ngSubmit and the button is never ngDisabled when the required fields are blank.

Stripped down version of the issue that still doesn't work:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="LoginController as loginCtrl">

        <form name="loginForm" role="form" ng-submit="loginCtrl.login()" novalidate></form>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" ng-model="loginCtrl.user.username" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" ng-model="loginCtrl.user.password" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group clearfix">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid">Login</button>
        </div>

        <pre>user data = {{loginCtrl.user | json}}</pre>

        <pre>form invalid = {{loginForm.$invalid}}</pre> <!-- always says false... but it is invalid -->

        </form>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp', [])

    .controller('LoginController', [function() { 

        var self = this;
        self.user = { username: 'asdf', password: 'asdf' };
        self.login = function() {
            console.log("hello world");
        };
    }]);

})();    
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.24/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: create a demo , code seems fine

Comment: Hi @charlietfl, tried it in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qn095gth/2/ but not loading

Comment: fiddle or plunker is much better as your link wil dissapear. Make sure in fiddle that you select `no-wrap` so code isn't in a dom loaded handler

Comment: I changed my above comment to have the fiddle, and it seems to be loading Angular now with no-wrap chosen, and it seems to work there

Comment: so why is it working on jsfiddle and not my version which the trimmed down versions are the same... I've include angularjs using https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.24/angular.min.js and jquery.

Comment: actually fiddle is failing (see console). Version of angular not supporting controllerAs I think.  but works here http://plnkr.co/edit/rgQzMsx1hAa9uMFUQFMW?p=preview Note that `user` in markup is changed to `loginCtrl.user`

Answer (score 0):

make sure that angular libraries are included.

https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/downloading

and have a look at these solutions
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2513

and if you like to see my working form...

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <form class="tab-pane active form-horizontal" id="first" name="userForm" novalidate ng-submit="save()">
        <h2>Sign up</h2>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : submitted && userForm.username.$invalid}">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3">UserName <span class="required">* </span> </label>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" required placeholder="username"/>
            </div>
            <p ng-show=" submitted && userForm.email.$invalid" class="help-block">Username is required.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : submitted && userForm.email.$invalid}">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Email <span class="required">* </span> </label>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" required placeholder="email"/>
            </div>
            <p ng-show=" submitted && userForm.email.$invalid" class="help-block">Email is required.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : submitted && userForm.password.$invalid}">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Password <span class="required">* </span> </label>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" required placeholder="1.2"/>
            </div>
            <p ng-show="submitted && userForm.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Confirm Password </label>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password_confirmation"
                       placeholder="password_confirmation"/>
            </div>
            <p ng-show="submitted && userForm.password_confirmation.$invalid" class="help-block">password_confirmation is required.</p>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="/app/assets/images"> Back</a>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submitted=true">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>


    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why include both the mininified and non-mininified source? And while I'm at it, the question seems to imply that AngularJS is functioning to some degree, so that suggestion seem unnecessary :)